# StringWithFormat returning non-NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, stringwithformat

I have a problem with `StringWithFormat` not working. The debugger says the returned string is not an `NSString` (and it is not null), thus my calls with the supposed `NSString` will not match a method selector, and my app crashes.

I am testing on XCode 4.5 iOS 6 settings (old project, no sub-projects).

This code will return something that is not an `NSString`:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\nTest to %@ (%@)\n", target, ipString]
```

If I insert a space as the first character in the format string, then the result is an `NSString`, i.e. the following works:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\nTest to %@ (%@)\n", target, ipString]
```

This code block also does not work. It returns something not an `NSString`. What am I doing wrong here ?

```
int TTL = 1;
NSString *ttl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" \n# %d", TTL] ;
TTL++;
[self textToParent:  ttl];     // Program crashes here. Debugger show ttl not NSString.
TTL--;
```

The error message is `ttl = (__NSCFString *) 0xwhatever @<variable is not NSString>`

Comment: error in debugger when displaying the variable is: ttl = (__NSCFString *) 0xwhatever @<variable is not NSString>

Comment: I've tested your code with Xcode 4.5 with iOS6 on real device, it runs well, the log says the result is `# 1`. your problem must be somewhere else, not here. what kind of class is the `self`? and what is inside the `-textToParent:` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the first two lines to..

```
  int TTL = 1;
        NSString *ttl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" \n# %@",[NSNumber numberWithInt:TTL] ] ;

   TTL++;
   [self textToParent: (NSString *) ttl];     //  Change here.
   TTL--;
```

Comment: I am getting more confused now, will try to recreate project later.

Comment: try typecasting it like this [self textToParent: (NSString *) ttl];

Comment: I changed from LVVM to GDB debugger, and things looks much better. Now I it looks like I have another problem. Even after typecasting to NSString *, my textToParent calls seems to fail, even those that used to work.

Comment: It seems like my self variable has been "destroyed", it is pointing to a zeroed out copy of my NSThread subclass. Earlier in the thread it worked. So the question is, why did it lose contents ? ARC ? Calling retain on self as the first step in my thread did no help.

Comment: My problem was, that when manipulating C structures (low level network buffers), I was running beyond the packet size, and thus killing the self variable. That is what caused all the problems.

Answer (score 0):

try bellow code...

```
int TTL = 1;
NSString *ttl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" \n# %@",[NSNumber numberWithInt:TTL]] ;
[ttl retain];
TTL++;
[self textToParent:  ttl];
TTL--;
```

hope this help you...

:)

Comment: error in debugger when displaying the variable is: ttl = (__NSCFString *) 0xwhatever @<variable is not NSString>

Comment: NSLog(@"\n\n ttl = %@",ttl); paste this line after [ttl retain] and see its give the output or not.. if give output then post the whole method 'textToParent' with return Type

Answer (score 0):

Consider that your debugger might not be quite perfect. Click on the variable in the debugger, right-click "print description".